# Having a little issue with a simple jQuery fadeOut?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadeout

I have a simple ID I want to fadeOut with jQuery after a button. However, when clicking on the respected button it doesn't work and nothing happens. Heres how I get JS file from different location like this:

```
<script src="http://myflashpics.com/v2/jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="http://myflashpics.com/v2/actions.js"></script>
```

Here's my action in my actions.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(function() {

  $(".profileLink").click(function() {
    $("#right_bar_content").fadeOut("slow");
  });

});

});
```

Here's some other HTML assosiated with it:

```
<img src="http://myflashpics.com/get_image.php?short_string=avqc&size=thumbnail" class="profileLink" />
<div id="right_bar_wrapper" id="right_bar_content">content here</div>
```

Please help!
Coulton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't have two separate ids for your div. Get rid of the `right_bar_wrapper` id and merge the CSS for the two ids.

Second, `$(` is just short-hand for `$(document).ready`; it shouldn't be nested. Remove one or the other.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".profileLink").click(function() {
        $("#right_bar_content").fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe the first attribute of an identical group is used and the others ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; I had guessed it was the other way 'round.

Comment: I did too until I answered another question here about something similar. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/RdQht/) for confirmation :)

Comment: Feel like a doofus, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are wrapping your code with DOM ready twice. This shouldn't be an error, but it is not good practice.

Your problem is your `div` has two `id` attributes, and the [first one being parsed is used](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/RdQht/) in the DOM. I believe a HTML attribute may only ever be used once on the same element.

Get rid of the first `id` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your element can't have two IDs.